# Href to a specific div (on the same page), with only a class

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have a button that slides to a specific div on the same page. I have previously been able to do it when the other div to target had a specific id, using href="#div_id".

However, the div I am currently trying to target only has a class, and I am unable to add an id to that specific div.

This is all in wordpress, and since I am completely new I don't know how to do it via javascript (have to hook into the specific button, and call a function - which is too complicated for me).

Best regards, and thanks in advance

Comment: Wait, did you say button? Buttons don't have hrefs.

Comment: I never get tired of posting [**Links are not Buttons and vice versa**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JavaScript, you can do this in the onload of your page. (Or at the end of the body, whatever you prefer.)

```
 document.querySelector('.yourclassname').id = 'yourchosenid';
```

where `yourclassname` is the class of the div and `yourchosenid` is the id you want to assign to it. Then you can use the href as usual with `href="#yourchosenid"`.

Note that both `yourclassname` and `yourchosenid` must be unique in order for this to work!

```html
<a href="#insertidhere">click here</a>
<div>This is a filler. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="whateverclassyouhave"><strong>This is the intended target!</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<script>
   document.querySelector('.whateverclassyouhave').id = 'insertidhere';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make url to `class` because class may be applied to many elements and `id` defines the unique element.

What you can do is try to override click behavior on class with JavaScript when class element matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting elements by class is not very reliable solution, unless you're careful with them and not repeat them. I would suggest something like that, in jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="js-scroll" data-target="yourClass">link</a>
```

and in JS file:

```
$('.js-scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTo: $(target).offset().top
    }, 600);
});
```

In this way, you will have a smooth scroll to your desired element.